# .htaccess doesnt protect files in folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have an simple .htaccess and a .passwd file for a password protection of an folder under apache2: /var/www/test

Works fine if i want to connect to example.com/test. 
But in the test folder is also a download.exe. If i connect to example.com/test/download.exe i can download the file without being asked for a username and a password.

How can i change that? The .htaccess file:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "protected area"
AuthUserFile /var/www/test/.passwd
Require valid-user
```

Comment: Try a different browser or a different computer to access example.com/test/download.exe before accessing example.com/test. Browser you are using can have cached the downloaded file or the credentials used.

Comment: Thanks, thats it! I already change the .passwd so i thought there cant be something cached. But i didnt know that firefox caches the downloads. I renamed the download.exe to download2.exe and it worked fine.

Comment: firefox is a bit of a pain in its willingness to cache `httpauth` authentications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a different browser or a different computer to access example.com/test/download.exe before accessing example.com/test. Browsers you are using can have cached the downloaded file or the credentials used.